Clausula LIKE SQL SERVER EN PHP
Que tal comunidad estoy intentanto ejecutar una consulta SQL en PHP usando LIKE pero obtengo el error: "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'."
           $statement = $conexion -> prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM LEADTIME WHERE MATERIAL LIKE '%' :material '%'"
            );
            $statement -> bindParam (':material',$material);

Tienen alguna idea de que esta mal ?
Gracias.

El error  "Incorrect syntax near '@P1'" indica que SQL Server no reconoce el parámetro :material dentro de la cadena de consulta. Para utilizar parámetros en SQL Server con PHP, debes emplear el signo ? como marcador de parámetro y utilizar bindParam para asignar los valores.
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM LEADTIME WHERE MATERIAL LIKE ?");
$statement->bindParam(1, '%' . $material . '%');

SQL Server, al igual que otros sistemas de gestión de bases de datos, tiene su propia sintaxis para ejecutar consultas parametrizadas. En este caso, el signo de interrogación (?) es el marcador de posición estándar que reconoce para representar un valor que será proporcionado más tarde. El uso de ":material" no forma parte de esta sintaxis y, por lo tanto, genera este error.

Desgraciadamente, esta solución abre las puertas a la inyección de SQL. Es una pésima práctica el concatenar cadenas que puedan venir de interacción de usuario.

Está mal el marcador (placeholder) de la consulta. Un marcador debe ser eso mismo, solo una referencia a otro valor que es quién tiene los parámetros:
$statement = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM LEADTIME WHERE MATERIAL LIKE :material"
);
$statement->bindParam(':material', '%'.$material.'%');

